# How can I build a electronically controlled valve for a 1/4 inch tube

Tags: valves, servo

I'm looking for a practical efficient way to open and close a 1/4 inch gravity fed hose. Initially I was thinking of using a Solenoid, but can't find anything suitable. My second thought was using a servo and valve. I was also looking into some sort of piezo valve but they seem very specialized and expensive.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious answer of just buying a off the shelf electrically-controlled valve?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [Plastic Water Solenoid Valve - 12V - 1/2" Nominal](https://www.adafruit.com/products/997) coupled with [1/2" to 1/4" adapter](https://www.fastenal.com/products/details/69254). You could use simple arduino microcontoller to control the valve. Below are some example images of the hardware.

[image]

[image]

Comment: need something more like this http://store.rainbird.com/1-4-inch-barb-valve-for-drip-irrigation-pack-of-2.html the one pictured is to large

Comment: Looks like you have found what you want. That is great. I was giving you a suggestion one way to solve your problem.

Comment: Well that's a valve, but still looking for a way to make it a soleniod

Comment: Well it is solenoid that opens and closes the valve.

Comment: Why re-invent the proverbial wheel?