# where to find / what to call a 3/4 inch air valve that can be opened/closed electrically?

Tags: airflow, valves, electrical

I'm looking for something like this air valve:

[image]
(as discussed in https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/12404/12007)

But I need to tube to be wider (3/4 in), the tube to be shorter (the shorter the better), and I would like it if the mechanism for opening and closing the valve wasn't so bulky. This is a picture of an air valve at a much larger scale:

[image]
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Suncourt-12-in-Normally-Closed-Automated-Damper-ZC112/204268743?cm_mmc=Shopping%7cVF%7cG%7c0%7cG-VF-PLA%7c&gclid=CjwKCAjwlIvXBRBjEiwATWAQIp6R6KVXc7l3PrZILy2NjFr2LsexUXmn6eohfsIsHXPDVXo3r9prZBoC_QgQAvD_BwE&dclid=CIXgsZqh2toCFQN6fgodAd8ElA

I'm hoping to find something like that at a 3/4 in scale, where the mechanism is proportionally smaller also.

I only need the valve to be able to withstand the pressure of a person exhaling, which I think is like 3 psi max. So I'm hoping something less bulky than the solenoid in the first link could be used.

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: Okay, well do you have a suggestion for another way I can hunt for this resource?

Comment: Go to a valve specialist - not a general store...

Comment: It's OK to ask for help with terminology to assist in your search rather than specific components. Your question is much more likely to get good answers if we don't have to follow links to understand what you are talking about (and your question will still make sense when the links die). Post the images in-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a 3/4" **magnetic** valve or **solenoid** valve. Google these terms, then talk to a supplier. As you want the mechanism inside the duct (or so it appears), you could also look for a magnetic or electrical ball valve. However I beleive at this small size, the electrical componentes outside the duct will be about the same size as the physical body of the valve.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, all of the models/pictures that came up with those searches are like my first image above, which is too heavy/bulky for my application. I will see if I can build what I need from smaller components.